# Check time (a user entered) between two times (out of an foreach)

Tags: php

I want to check if a user entered a time (start, end) which already exist or have a conflict with the times out of the foreach.

I tried to put the existing times in an array to check the new user data with the data from the array but it didnt worked :I

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $mitarbeitername = $_POST['mitarbeiter'];
    //echo "Organisator: " .$mitarbeitername;

    $reservierungvon = $_POST['zeitstart'];
    //echo "Von: " .$reservierungvon;

    $reservierungbis = $_POST['zeitende'];
    //echo "Bis: " .$reservierungbis;
}

foreach($value as $value) {
    $startarray[] = $start = $value->Start->DateTime;($value);
}

$checkendtime = array();
foreach($value as $value) {
    $endarray[] = $start = $value->End->DateTime;($value);
}

if ($reservierungvon == $startarray || $reservierungbis == $endarray || $reservierungvon < $startarray && $endarray > $reservierungbis) {
    echo "conflict!";
} else {
    echo "no conflict!";
}
```

This is the foreach where im getting the existing meeting-times:

```
foreach ($result->value as & $value) {
                $start = $value->Start->DateTime;
                $start = substr($start, 11, -11);
                $ende = $value->End->DateTime;
                $ende = substr($ende, 11, -11);
                $organisierer = $value->Organizer->EmailAddress->Name;
}
```

And in this form the user can create new meetings if there isnt some conflicts with existings meetings:

```
<label for="psw"><br><b>Zeit der Reservierung:</b></label><br>
von <input type="time" name="timestart"> Uhr bis <input type="time" name="timeend"> Uhr <br>
```

It would be great if I can check the times out of the foreach with the new times from the user.

The user will get a message if there is a conflict or not. So he can correct his times.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to put the existing times in an array to check the new user data with the data from the array but it didnt worked :I

Comment: Can you please show the code that doesn't work? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Would be great to show us this! We may be able say you why it didn't work, and give you a solution.

Comment: I added it in the Question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check in the loop or otherwise the following scenarios:

For each existing interval (B):

1. The entered interval starts within B
2. The entered interval ends within B
3. The entered interval starts before B and ends after B

if any of these are TRUE you have a conflict, otherwise not.

Comment: Okey, I will try it again and follow your information. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you check my code? I put it in my Question under "I tried ...". It still not working perfect.

Comment: Try dividing the task into steps, e.g. 1) populate and print an array of all existing intervals, 2) take an interval and check if its start time is within any existing intervals.. etc.  hardcode the user entered interval instead of reading post values,  print out immediate results of each step,